# How to install psqlparse python package in jupyter?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to install psqlparse package in jupyter with this command:

```
pip install -U psqlparse==1.0rc7
```

But there is an error. Is there a way I can install this package using jupyter or conda?

In addition, the version 1.0rc7 file of this package and the setup.py file are available in my system, if it helps.

```
Collecting psqlparse==1.0rc7
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/9e/b919842a2cfc27a212a98149c6449cedfbf388a370257af7504651925016/psqlparse-1.0rc7.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from psqlparse==1.0rc7) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: psqlparse
  Building wheel for psqlparse (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for psqlparse (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command E:\Anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Soha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g1sf8ekh\\psqlparse\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Soha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-mla477je --python-tag cp37:
  E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:475: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.0-rc7' to '1.0rc7'
    normalized_version,
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse
  copying psqlparse\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse
  copying psqlparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
  copying psqlparse\nodes\nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
  copying psqlparse\nodes\parsenodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
  copying psqlparse\nodes\primnodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
  copying psqlparse\nodes\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
  copying psqlparse\nodes\value.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
  copying psqlparse\nodes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
  running build_ext
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for psqlparse
Failed to build psqlparse
Installing collected packages: psqlparse
  Running setup.py install for psqlparse: started
    Running setup.py install for psqlparse: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command E:\Anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Soha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g1sf8ekh\\psqlparse\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Soha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-woylvw9h\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:475: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.0-rc7' to '1.0rc7'
      normalized_version,
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse
    copying psqlparse\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse
    copying psqlparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
    copying psqlparse\nodes\nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
    copying psqlparse\nodes\parsenodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
    copying psqlparse\nodes\primnodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
    copying psqlparse\nodes\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
    copying psqlparse\nodes\value.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
    copying psqlparse\nodes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psqlparse\nodes
    running build_ext
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    
    ----------------------------------------
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  Failed building wheel for psqlparse
Command "E:\Anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Soha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g1sf8ekh\\psqlparse\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Soha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-woylvw9h\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Soha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1sf8ekh\psqlparse\
```

Comment: This package needs a library written in C, which it has to compile.  Do you have Visual Studio (or some other C compiler) installed?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed Visual Studio and Codeblocks

Comment: Check [pglast.](https://pglast.readthedocs.io/en/v3/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't. According to the README, `psqlparse` is no longer maintained, and the last release was 3 years ago. It was also an rc release, so probably something was left unfinished.

Find another package.

Comment: I need to parse postgresql queries, can another package do this?

Comment: SQL is SQL.  There are several SQL parsing modules in Python, like sqlparse.

Comment: What `psqlparse` does is like this:
`from psqlparse import parse_dict`                  
 `parse_tree = parse_dict(schema)`
How can I do this with `sqlparse` or another package?